# [JavaFX]how to create buttons for each item listed on a server?

Tags: javafx, sftp

Let me explain a little more, I made an application where you can upload files via FTP, which I miss so far is: upload files, download files and see directories and files created on the server, I am using this code to lists. ..

```
String[] files1 = ftpClient.listNames();
        printNames(files1);
private static void printNames(String files[]) {
    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
        for (String aFile: files) {
            System.out.println(aFile);
            //dir.setId(aFile);
        }
    }
}
```

I sample files terminal correctly, the point is I want to create a button for each file, for example, an image showing a button with options as well as your name and a thumbnail icon, any suggestions?

Comment: "you have options" <= what does this mean?  What would you expect for an answer here?

Comment: No need to be sorry, I'm just asking for clarification of the question, is all. The more specific and targeted the question is, the quicker and easier it is to get answers.  Don't worry if the english is not perfect, but it helps if it is clear.  For example, a standard menu button cannot have options, but a [SplitMenuButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitMenuButton.html) can.  SplitMenuButtons are a bit unusual, but perhaps that is what you are asking for?

Comment: What is the connection between images and buttons? I didn't get that part by default `Button`s don't show images, but you could show a image inside a `Button` object or you could use them as background. Also the action triggered by a button click could result in a specific image being displayed... Please clarify the desired behavior. This should increase your chances of getting a (good) answer.

Comment: Hello, thank you both, I am newbie in java, and I want to accomplish is an effect like dropbox to upload any file ... like herr [link](http://www.nationsabroad.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Screen-Shot-2013-03-17-at-5.42.53-PM.png) ... but I have no idea how to do it ....so when I upload a file to my ftp server, display information (details) file ...